# Removing React's warning about missing props in tests

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

so when testing with Jest, sometimes I want to test what happens if a prop is missing, even when I set this prop as required. As I've noticed that you can't trust what is passed to a component at all time (especially when data comes from the server)

Now of course there are warning being displayed when the props are missing and it makes the running tests a bit messy. The tests pass just fine and the whole suite passes, but it gets really busy on the screen.

My question would be, is there a way to remove these warnings, or a way to trick React into thinking the prop is there? I know I could set them as not required and pass a default but I'd prefer not do that.

Thanks

Comment: add default prop values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want the logs to go away so that the output is cleaner, you can mock the `console.log` like this:

`console.log = jest.fn()`

I would do it in a `beforeAll` and then make sure you reset it after your tests are done with a `console.log.mockClear()`

Or they might be `console.warn`. I can't quite remember.

Comment: hey @max-millington thanks for your reply. I like it, however it's kinda like pushing the issue away. Isn't there a more Reacty way of doing this? Or should I simply set my props as non required with a default?